# Is python parameters' default value accepted by args or kwargs?

Tags: python, parameters, default-value

I found a strange instance when I try to make a testing decorator. code like this:

```
def doublefunc(fn):
    def warpped(*arg, **kwargs):
        arg = (i if type(i) is not int else i*2 for i in arg)
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            kwargs[k] = v *2 if type(v) is int else v
        return fn(*arg, **kwargs)
    return warpped

@doublefunc
def add(x, y, m, z=10, v='bbaa'):
    print 'x=%s, y=%s, m=%s, z=%s, v=%s' % (x, y, m, z, v)
    return x + y + z
```

when I call function like this:

```
print add(1, 1, 'teststring')
```

The returned value is **14** but not 24. That means the default value of parameter **z** in function **add**, is not accepted in decorator function inner. Why?

Comment: `print add(1, 1, 'teststring')` returns **12**! And it is correct! Are you sure you received **14**? Why do you expect 24?

Comment: @EbraHim It returns 14 on my computer (Python 2.7, Ubuntu Kylin). Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It returns 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky, but you can get unpassed default arguments with some use of the `inspect` module

```
import inspect

def get_unpassed_defaults(fn, args, kwargs):
        args_len = len(args) + len(kwargs)
        argspec = inspect.getargspec(fn)

        defaults = argspec.defaults
        default_names = argspec.args[-len(defaults):]

        number_of_args = len(argspec.args)
        number_of_positional_args = number_of_args - len(argspec.defaults)
        number_of_kwargs = number_of_args - number_of_positional_args
        number_of_kwargs_passed_as_positional = len(args) - number_of_positional_args

        default_values = defaults[number_of_kwargs_passed_as_positional:]
        default_names = default_names[number_of_kwargs_passed_as_positional:]
        defaults_dict = dict(zip(default_names, default_values))

        for kwarg_name in kwargs:
            if kwarg_name in defaults_dict:
                defaults_dict.pop(kwarg_name)

        return defaults_dict
```

And then leverage this in `doublefunc`:

```
def doublefunc(fn):
    def wrapped(*arg, **kwargs):
        unpassed_defaults = get_unpassed_defaults(fn, arg, kwargs)
        kwargs.update(unpassed_defaults)

        arg = (i if type(i) is not int else i*2 for i in arg)
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            kwargs[k] = v *2 if type(v) is int else v

        return fn(*arg, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@doublefunc
def add(x, y, m, z=10, v='bbaa'):
    print 'x=%s, y=%s, m=%s, z=%s, v=%s' % (x, y, m, z, v)
    return x + y + z

print add(1, 1, "teststring", v=3)
```

Gives:

```
x=2, y=2, m=teststring, z=20, v=6
24
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as vanza  said, This is a duplicate question. The inner warpper of decorator has no access to the warpped function. Thank vanza too!

Comment: @HenryJohn but the inner wrapper of the decorator *does* have access as I demonstrated.  My code does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that decorator function doesn't look for inner attributes (in this case default kwargs) of wrapped function. If you still want to do this then you just have to play with dictionaries.

> Won't work with Python 2 because there is no `getfullargspec` method, so for that follow @Nolen Royalty's answer

**For Python 3**

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def doublefunc(fn):
        def wrapped(*arg, **kwargs):
            defaults = (inspect.getfullargspec(fn).kwonlydefaults)
            defaults.update(kwargs)
            kwargs = defaults
            arg = (i if type(i) is not int else i*2 for i in arg)
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                kwargs[k] = v *2 if type(v) is int else v
            return fn(*arg, **kwargs)
        return wrapped

>>> @doublefunc
def add(x, y, m, *args, z=10, v='bbaa'):
    print('x={0}, y={1}, m= {2}, z={3}, v={4}'.format(x,y,m,z,v))
    return x + y + z

>>> print(add(1, 1, 'teststring', v=1))
```

**Result:**

```
x=2, y=2, m= teststring, z=20, v=2
24
```

Comment: You can (and should) use parenthesis with print statements in Python 2, so the code will work in both. For small dictionaries, you can just use `.items()` in both as well, it will just be eager in 2 and lazy in 3. For large dictionaries, I usually just import `iteritems` from the `six` library.

Comment: `getfullargspec` doesn't exist in Python 2.

Comment: Thank you, So it's just solution for Python 3. @Nolen Royalty